# How to filter featured products slider by category?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to display a "featured products slider" on the Category Page of the WooCommerce shop in such a way that only 'featured' products of the current category (or a specific child category) will be displayed in the slider. 
I've placed the code below in the functions.php file of my child-theme.
I tried adding this conditional in archive.php:

```
   if(is_product_category('slug'){echo featured_products_slider_fun($atts, $content);}
```

I can't figure out how to combine this condition with the function below to essentially show 'featured products' of a certain category'.

===========

function featured_products_slider_func( $atts,  $content ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'num' => 4
    ), $atts ) );

```
$return = '';

$first_product_title = "";
$first_product_excerpt = "";

function get_the_popular_excerpt(){
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 190);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'. <a href="'.get_permalink().'">view product</a>';

    return $excerpt;
}

$post = new WP_Query(array(
'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => '_featured',
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
    'posts_per_page' => $num
));

$return .= '<div class="featured-slider-outer box clearfix"><div class="featured-slider-inner">';
    $return .= '<ul class="products featured-slider">';
    $selected_class = " selected";

    if ($post ->have_posts()) : while ($post ->have_posts()) : $post ->the_post();

        global $product;

        if( $selected_class != "" ) {
            $first_product_title = get_the_title();
            $first_product_excerpt = get_the_popular_excerpt();
        }

        $return .= '<li class="product' . $selected_class . '">';

            $return .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, "blog-two-column");

            if ($price_html = $product->get_price_html()) :
                $return .= '<span class="price">';
                    $return .= $price_html;
                $return .= '</span>';
            endif;

            $return .= "<div class='none'>";
                $return .= "<h3 id='infos-title'>" . get_the_title() . "</h3>";
                $return .=  "<div id='infos-excerpt'>" . get_the_popular_excerpt() . "</div>";
            $return .= "</div>";
        $return .= '</li>';

        $selected_class = "";

    endwhile;

    $return .= '</ul>';
$return .= '</div>';

$return .= '<div class="featured-slider-right">';
    $return .= '<button class="btn-left"></button><button class="btn-right"></button><h2>' . $first_product_title . '</h2>';
    $return .= '<div class="description">' . $first_product_excerpt . '</div>';
$return .= '</div>';

$return .= '</div>';

else:
    $return = __("No featured products found!", "shopifiq");
endif;

return $return;
```

}

add_shortcode( 'featured_products_slider', 'featured_products_slider_func' );

Comment: I'm at a stage now that I'm able to show the relevant products in the 'featured products slider' on the correct page (i.e show on 'cat1' all featured products that parent category is 'cat1'). To finish up this fix I'm looking to either to remove the duplicate products because at the moment the category page shows both category products and sub-category products. I want to only show the sub-category products either in the sub-category page or the slider. How do I do that?

Comment: I found a solution for duplicate content.. see the following link: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-products-of-subcategories-within-main-categories?replies=6#post-4899084